# What is the purpose of the HTML name attribute?

Tags: html

What is the purpose of the `name` attribute on `input`, `span`, or `div` tags? Should an `id` tag be used instead?

Example from [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label):

```
<label for="User">Click me</label>
<input type="text" id="User" name="Name" />
```

Comment: name is used for forms

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.name

Comment: "name gets or sets the name property of a DOM object; it only applies to the following elements: <a>, <applet>, <button>, <form>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <map>, <meta>, <object>, <param>, <select>, and <textarea>."

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `name` attribute identifies the input `value` if it is sent to a server via a traditional `GET` or `POST` of a form.

Specific to the example if you had:

```
<form action="http://localhost" method="POST">
    <label for="User">Click me</label>
    <input type="text" id="User" name="Name" value="foo" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and you submit the form, the server `localhost` will receive a content body like:

```
Name=foo
```

which as another post mentions, is usually parsed by a server side language like PHP into something easier to work with.

The `id` attribute identifies the input to the `DOM`. If you specify an input with no `name` but an `id` and try to submit it via a `GET` or `POST` it will not be parsed correctly by the server.

Answer (score 14):

In an `input` element, the `name` attribute defines the name of the control. Only controls that have a name can be “successful”, i.e. may contribute to the form data set sent to a server. Thus, it is indispensable in order to make the value of the control submitted to server-side processing. The `id` attribute has nothing to do with this; it has its own uses, such as helping to associate a label with the control, as in the example.

Consequently, the `name` attribute is not needed if you need not have the control value submitted. For example, if you have a single submit button like `<input type=submit value=Send>`, you don’t need it; but if you have several submit buttons and you need to recognize, server-side, which one was used, you need it. If the form data is not sent to server-side processing but handled only in client-side processing, the `name` attribute is not used, as you can access the values with other means.

In `span` and `div` elements, a `name` attribute is invalid in all HTML versions. If used, it will simply be ignored, except in the sense that it is stored (like any invalid attributes) in the `attributes` property in the DOM and can be accessed in client-side scripting.

Considering the general question as in the question title, the `name` attribute is allowed and recognized in some elements, disallowed and ignored in others, and when allowed, its meaning is defined in the definition of the element. There is not that much in common between these definitions.

Some confusion has been caused by statements like “the `name` attribute is deprecated/obsolete”. Such statements are correct for this attribute in some elements in some HTML versions, but in `input` elements for example, it remains official and necessary.

Answer (score 5):

*Name* should be used on form fields like `<input>`, and it should not be used on `<span>` or `<div>`.
*Name* is obsolete on anchor tags, and you should use *id* instead.

Check this [Mozilla link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.name) (or https://web.archive.org/web/20200803104412/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name) for more:

> *name* gets or sets the name property of a DOM object; it only applies to the following elements: `<a>`, `<applet>`, `<button>`, `<form>`, `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input>`, `<map>`, `<meta>`, `<object>`, `<param>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`

Comment: what is the purpose of the name tag? If I don't have it, what difference will it make to my form?

Comment: If you drop this attribute, the value from that input won't be used for submission to the server: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set

Answer (score 3):

If you define a link (a-Element) and define a name for it, you can use it as an anchor.
See: *[HTML <a> Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp)*

Or more generally: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.name (or https://web.archive.org/web/20200803104412/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name)

Comment: That page says the name attribute is invalid for HTML5

Comment: The second link is effectively broken. It redirects to `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API`

Answer (score 0):

The *name* attribute is for when you are using an additional language such as PHP to read and write data to the database or other files. To refer to the text field above, you would refer to its name which is "Name" and write the value in the "Name" text field to the database.

Comment: Is that to avoid using jQuery to select fields by class or id?

Comment: It's something different - jQuery uses class names and id names. I know PHP uses the name of the html tag to reference it..