# JavaScript function run via onload isn't updating href attribute as expected

Tags: javascript, html, onload, setattribute

I am working with two sites hosted on the same host that want to share some html files by having symbolic links linking directory trees but have independent "branding" when the pages are viewed, so I figured that getting the appropriate data could be discovered using `window.location.hostname` and then performing "branding customizations" based on that data, the most important of which is just a simple link back to the appropriate site's contact data. So, I want to change both the link and the linked text.

No problem, I figured, just use either an `"onload="` in the body to run a function or put a `window.onload=` at the script level.

The function fires, no problem there, but it isn't updating the item I want to update because it keeps responding that the target of the `.setAttribute` is null. Here's an excerpt:

```
    function setContact()
    {
      // var ourURL = window.location.href;
      var DN = window.location.hostname;
      // if structure using DN to come up with the changes omitted
      // "contactLnk" is both the name of the anchor and the name
      // of the variable set by the if structure
      var targetLink = document.getElementById("contactLnk");
      targetLink.setAttribute('href', contactLnk);
    }
  </script>
```

The function runs and but has no effect and the java script console says:

```
TypeError: targetLink is null
```

I have some similar but different code that works fine, but it's all initiated by something like mouseover or onclick, etc.

Obviously I'm "doing it wrong." Insight appreciated

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Some Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#AAD7B9" text="#000000" onload="setContact();">
  <script type = "text/javascript">
    function setContact()
    {
      var DN = window.location.hostname;
      var targetLink = document.getElementById("contactLnk");
      targetLink.setAttribute('href', "http://"+DN+"/index.html");
    }
  </script>

<p>
Nav section deleted in whole. Has nothing to do with it anyway.
</p>

<p>
<a name="contactLnk" onload="setContact();" href="not.us">Some Link Text</a>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Either you have you have no element with that id or the script is running before the page is fully loaded

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks, but there are copyright issues here. I guess I could mock up something. Maybe it would suffice to just describe it in basic terms? Otherwise it'll take me a while to hack up something suitable. In short, there's an opening html tag, then a head (complete), then a body tag that encompasses the whole rest of what's there, then a series of functions, followed by a <nav> section that defines a rather complicated menu with a few divs, and  finally a body of rather bland html and a closing body tag. Need more?

Comment: No.You have to show us the code or we can't help you. By the way, client-side code is not copywritable only the content is.

Comment: @ScottMarcus OK, code, and, BTW, I don't believe you about what's copyrightable or not (Amazon's one click patent anyone?), and even if our wrong that ignores also the sensitivity of clients who don't want their stuff out there in a forum like this - speculation on who they're sharing with, etc - none of anyone else's business. So, I cut it all down to size - this code here doesn't work either. Like I said, all that other stuff just doesn't matter.

Comment: `getElementById()` does exactly that: Gets an element *by its `id`*. Your `<a>` doesn't have an `ID`.

Comment: I don't want to argue with you. Client-side code is accessible to everyone and is not copyrightable. But, that is really besides the point. No one can help you with a coding problem if you don't share the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change name to id in the html element so that the getElementById will work.

```
<a id="contactLnk" onload="setContact();" href="not.us">Some Link Text</a>
```

As you have it, there is no element with id of "contactLnk".

Comment: Or add an ID attribute with the same value.

Comment: DOAH! That was it! I knew it had to be something stupid! :-)

Comment: @isherwood - true.  But what do people use name for anyway?  I have yet to find a use for it.

Comment: @AgapwIesu Form inputs, for one. A form input without a `name` will not be included in the data sent to the server. [More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061651/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-html-name-attribute)

Comment: @Santi - of course.  It's been a while since I used it.  Been using asp.net's instantiated elements for so long that I totally forgot that.